# Visual Studio 2015 multiple project template

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-templates

I want to use a custom template I created with VS 2013 Update 5 in VS 2015.

The template works with VS 2013 Update 5, but not in VS 2015.

I've opened the solution from which the projects are exported as templates in VS 2015, and exported the 5 projects from the solution to the folder "My Exported Templates" under "Visual Studio 2015".

Under "My Exported Templates", I created a root .vstemplate file, which contains the ProjectTemplateLink tags for the 5 included projects. The project names are substituted by $safeprojectname$ here.

In the sub folders of the exported template projects, I've edited the .csproj 
files to include the ProjectReference ... tags for the referenced projects.
The project names are substituted by $ext_projectname$ here.

When I create a new Visual Studio Project from the template, in VS 2013 Update 5, the referenced projects names are substituted properly, but not in Visual Studio 2015.

Former, the same problems occurred in Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 - I think it works since Visual Studio 2013 update 2, but I'm only sure that it works under VS 2013 Update 5.

Thanks for any help!

TomK

Answer (score 1):

The Problem only occurs when I open a Visual Studio 2013 Solution in Visual Studio 2015 and use it as a Visual Studio 2015 Solution.

I've built up the solution from the ground in Visual Studio 2015 and exported the projects, and then it worked.